# Spyder / Jedi - code completion refusing to work

Tags: python, numpy, autocomplete, spyder, jedi

Say I have numpy arrays, for example.

Code completion works well enough when I press tab after a call to the `numpy.array` function.

[image]

and as long as I don't *DO* anything with it, it will continue to work fine:

[image]

However, the moment I do something:

[image]

[image]

I can press `tab` until my keyboard breaks, it won't give me any suggestions.

Which is rather unsatisfying. Anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Spyder **3.1**, and the latest Spyder version (as of March 3/2017) is **3.1.3**, so please update to that version.

*Note 1*: For some strange reason this is only working on Python 3. So please be sure to be using that version of Python. We'll try to fix things for Python 2 in the future.

*Note 2*: There is a bug about Spyder not being able to show completions after `a = a.reshape(2,3)`. We were not aware of that, sorry.

Comment: We haven't tested Python 3.6 too much. Could you try with 3.5?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that you really found a bug in this case.

Comment: Tried with 3.5 and it didn't change anything.